# How do I narrow the column gap between two image columns in a table?

Tags: html, css

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3sr65bx2/3/

I tried many different basic approaches, nothing seems to be working. All I want to do is narrow the gap between the two columns. How can I easily adjust the code to narrow the gap? This noobie I would greatly appreciate the help!

HTML & CSS

```css
.box2 {
  background: grey;
  padding: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolioimg {
  background: yellow;
}

td img {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box2">
  <p>
    To be, or not to be: that is the question: whether 'tis nobler in the mind to suffer the slings and arrows of outrageous fortune, or to take arms against a sea of troubles, and by opposing end them? To die: to sleep; no more; and, by a sleep to say we
    end the heart-ache and the thousand natural shocks that flesh is heir to, 'tis a consummation devoutly to be wish'd.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="portfolioimg">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/fjvm1u9xz/pic1.png" </td>
        <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/4myvqxf5z/pic2.png" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/87ur9ueh3/pic3.png" </td>
        <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/3lyn1kdjb/pic4.png" </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/x14banptj/pic5.png" </td>
        <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/ctqviei2f/pic6.png" </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, I think you have to just use `max-width:80%` to the `img` and `text-align:right` to the first `td` of every `tr`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.portfolioimg {
  background: yellow;
}

td img {
  max-width: 80%;
}

tr td:first-child {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolioimg">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/fjvm1u9xz/pic1.png"></td>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/4myvqxf5z/pic2.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/87ur9ueh3/pic3.png"></td>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/3lyn1kdjb/pic4.png"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/x14banptj/pic5.png"></td>
      <td><img src="https://s13.postimg.org/ctqviei2f/pic6.png"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the css of td

```
td{
margin-right: -40px;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, closes the gap. However, do you know why the yellow background disappeared? 

It also appears that the columns, for some reason, are slightly uneven (the right column sits slightly below the left one)

Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/3sr65bx2/38/

Comment: That is because you are using float td img. And I don't understand what you trying to do. If u want to use responsive table then the code is more simple than this. If you tell me exactly what you want to do then I can code for you.

Comment: But you can use this code to remove the top space td:nth-child(2){
  margin-top:-2px;
}